# Can you mutate an object of custom type when it's declared as constant?

Tags: c++

In our codebase, Pytorch, there are several areas where an object is declared as `const` but the object's member variables are eventually modified. e.g., see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/Resize.cpp#L29

This particular function here ends up modifying `output`, which is declared as `const`. Under what situations can you modify an object declared as `const` and is there an acceptable practice on whether or not this should be done?

Comment: maybe post the actual code?

Comment: *"that seems to modify `obj`"* Can you elaborate on this point? Generally you cannot modify a `const` object, except for members which are `mutable`. Trying to do modify a `const` might appear to work, but it is Undefined Behavior and the result could be anything.

Comment: What you *can* do in C++ and what you *should* or *shouldn't* do aren't always the same thing. If you declare something as `const`, then don't try to modify it.

Comment: @littleadv. It's the pytorch codebase https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/Resize.cpp#L29. This function here ends up modifying `output`, declared as `const`

Comment: You can declare the modified members `mutable`, you can do `const_cast`, which is not allowed (UB) for originally const variables, you can modify objects pointed to by const pointers, you can create, modify and return them.

Comment: In this case it looks like `const` is being used to prevent the *user* from altering the object. The library knows what's safe to mess with and what isn't, and messes freely.

Comment: @Sebastian Ah I see. I had thought that declaring a member var as `mutable` only allows member functions declared as `const` to modify it.

Comment: Note the *This is a hack, longer term solutions are in the issue* comment! Not sure how `Tensor` is defined but, attempting similar code with a `std::vector` won't compile.

Comment: I think it is because PImpl is used in Torch: Pointer to Implementation. And the pointer itself is const, but not the pointed to object. `const Impl* const impl` vs `Impl* const impl`

Comment: About the `mutable` functions with `const` 'postfix' have a `const *` `this` pointer. Should be the same as when the object is const itself. But I am not 100% sure about that.

Comment: Lacking details? Seems clear as day to me. And it really is difficult to add an answer addressing the _root_ question when it is insta-closed.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Sorry about that. I tried to simplify the question and I think I made it worse. Should've just posted the original code in the first place

Comment: @user5965026 maybe incorporate some of your clarifying comments into the question body to have it reopened. It's a good question

Comment: @littleadv I'm actually going to ask a somewhat related question that I'll link to here and maybe also reopen this. I'll link once I'm done posting it

Comment: Here is a related question that I just opened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855661/allowing-a-function-to-mutate-a-const-objects-member-variable

Will try to edit this question to make it clearer

Comment: `const` is mostly a tool for the user to make intention more clear and be automatically checked. (Except some const variables being put into r/o memory on some embedded platforms) there is no difference, how the compiled binary looks like. Therefore there are different interpretations and usages of const: Strictly language-oriented ones (nothing may be changed, also no referring subobjects may be exhorted non-const) and logical application-guided const, where caches and linked other objects are excluded from being r/o. There is no general answer, what can or should be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It is doing so through a ([eventual](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/Resize.cpp#L123)) call to [`TensorBase::unsafeGetTensorImpl`](https://codebrowser.bddppq.com/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/core/TensorBase.h.html#_ZNK2at10TensorBase19unsafeGetTensorImplEv) which returns `TensorBase*`, a mutable pointer, even though is declared as `const` and as such is safe to call in this scenario.

As the method name suggests, this is unsafe.

Comment: A "mutable" pointer here means the stuff stored at the memory th pointer is pointing to is mutable and not that the pointer itself is mutable, right?

Comment: Well, the pointer itself is also mutable, but yes - it points to `TensorBase` and not `const TensorBase`

Answer (score 1):

### You can, but you are betraying your users

A lot of times we get hung up on what we *can* do and/or get away with. But we forget that programming is designed for *humans* to communicate *ideas*. And the programming environment is designed to help us do that correctly and succinctly.

So yes, you could, at any time, throw off the `const`ness of your target object(s) and do what you like. If you are lucky no future user will find a way and attempt to pass something that is actually in a section of memory marked as read-only.

But the purpose of marking a thing as “**const**” is that you (the programmer) personally *guarantee* the users of a function/method/whatever that ***it will not attempt to modify the object***, *for any reason*.

To then sneakily modify it behind your users’ collective back, totally outside their expectations, is just plain Wrong™.

Don’t do it.

Consequently, I suggest you recommend fixing your codebase to be correct: remove the `const`s. It will *not* break any existing code using it, so that helps if you need to convince anyone to make your interface declare itself truthfully.

EDIT: An “output” object should never be “const” anyway. Functional languages like Haskell, for example, go through a lot of pains to separate mutable output and immutable objects (via *Monads*, in case you are curious to read more).

Comment: I assume you recommend to remove `const`ness for the specific class of the OP and not in general? There are user cases for `const` output objects: If they are an existing data strucure and: the input is `const`, if they are shared, if they are expensive or forbidden to be copied (and they only copy should not be changed). But in general it is the user's turn to store the result as const.