# Allowing a function to mutate a const object's member variable

Tags: c++, constants, immutability, mutable

This is related to the (currently) closed question I asked earlier: [Can you mutate an object of custom type when it's declared as constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855242/can-you-mutate-an-object-of-custom-type-when-its-declared-as-constant)

Suppose we have something that looks like the following:

```
class test 
{
public:
  test() : i{4}, ptr{&i} {};
  int i;
  int *ptr;
  int *get_ptr() const {return ptr;}
};

void func(const test &t, int j) {
  *(t.get_ptr()) = j;
  // auto ptr = t.get_ptr();
  // *ptr = j;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  test t;
  std::cout << t.i << std::endl;
  func(t, 5);
  std::cout << t.i << std::endl;
}
```

We have this `func` that takes in a `const test &`. When I see this signature (and if I didn't look at the implementation of the function), it makes me want to assume that nothing in `t` will get modified; however, the member variable `i` is able to be modified through the `ptr` member variable, as we see here.

I don't usually write code that end up working this way, so I'm wondering if code like this is discouraged?

Furthermore, is it reasonable to assume (most of the time) that an object declared as `const` will not be mutated?

Comment: This is a great example of C++ allowing you to shoot yourself in the foot.  `int *ptr` can point to an internal `int` during construction, because `const` objects only become `const` after construction.  Footgun locked and loaded.

Comment: You're cheating: You don't *directly* modify the passed object (for example, try changing what the `ptr` member points to). The fact that it points at another member variable is something the compiler won't check.

Answer (score 4):

Yes code like this is definitely discouraged.  It completely ignores the reason we have the const keyword in the first place.   The function is deliberately modifying something that it is advertising it will not modify

That means that whoever wrote the `get_ptr()` function messed up because they declared it const but let it return a pointer to non-const object (so one that can be changed, defeating the purpose of declaring the function `const`)

If whatever `get_ptr()` returns could properly be modified by such a function then it should be an implementation detail, a private (or protected) variable marked with the `mutable` keyword.

`test::get_ptr()` should have two overloads.

```
const int* get_ptr() const { return ptr; }
int*       get_ptr()       { return ptr; }
```

If `func()` wants to change the `test` object given to it then it should take `test&`, not `const test&`

Comment: Oops you're right.  My eyes glossed over.  Thought they were changing the pointer, not the value pointed to.  Fixed

Answer (score 3):

The key is here:

```
  int *get_ptr() const {return ptr;}
```

You define `get_ptr` as `const` which is akin to saying "*get_ptr is not going to change any attributes of the class*". And it doesn't. It returns the *value* of the attribute `ptr`, which is a `int*`, and points to a *mutable* instance of an `int` which *happens* to be an attribute of the class as well.

The compiler has no way of knowing this, so from the compiler's perspective the promise was kept. However in reality you're circumventing the `const` qualifier and allowing to mutate an otherwise immutable attribute.

Not the best of coding practices, but whoever writes such code should, obviously, not expect for `i` to remain as it was set in the class methods if `get_ptr` is ever called.